# update class label outside class

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def check_file_type():
    test = Gui()
    test.info_label['text'] = ''
    inputpath = r'C:\...'
    files = (file for file in os.listdir(inputpath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(inputpath, file)))
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pass
        else:
            jpg_to_png(file)

...

class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = tk.Tk()
        self.gui.title('Smart Archive')
        self.gui.geometry('500x500')

        self.scan_png_button = tk.Button(self.gui, text='Scan files', relief='groove', command = check_file_type())
        self.scan_png_button.place(x=15, y=15)
        self.info_label = tk.Label(self.gui, text='On Hold')
        self.info_label.place(x=15, y=40)
```

i'm trying to update "self.info_label" from outside class, using Gui().info_lable['text'] but i got this error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

so... is there a method to update a label outside a class?

Answer (score 2):

Use .config() and change the features that you want like here I changed the text to ' '.
Also don't put () while calling the function from the command in buttons.

```
def check_file_type():

    app.info_label.config(text='')
    inputpath = r'C:\...'
    files = (file for file in os.listdir(inputpath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(inputpath, file)))
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pass
        else:
            jpg_to_png(file)


class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = tk.Tk()
        self.gui.title('Smart Archive')
        self.gui.geometry('500x500')

        self.scan_png_button = tk.Button(self.gui, text='Scan files', relief='groove', command = check_file_type)
        self.scan_png_button.place(x=15, y=15)
        self.info_label = tk.Label(self.gui, text='On Hold')
        self.info_label.place(x=15, y=40)

app=Gui()
```

Answer (score 2):

2 problems there. The first is that you can't have `()` on the end of a command argument. The second is that you can't create the class from the called function. Try like this:

```
def check_file_type():
    test.info_label['text'] = ''
    inputpath = r'C:\...'
    files = (file for file in os.listdir(inputpath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(inputpath, file)))
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pass
        else:
            jpg_to_png(file)

class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = tk.Tk()
        self.gui.title('Smart Archive')
        self.gui.geometry('500x500')

        self.scan_png_button = tk.Button(self.gui, text='Scan files', relief='groove', command = check_file_type)
        self.scan_png_button.place(x=15, y=15)
        self.info_label = tk.Label(self.gui, text='On Hold')
        self.info_label.place(x=15, y=40)

test = Gui()
```